# How to create a live-cd that launches debian-installer and works properly?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, livecd, live-build

I'm trying to create a custom `Debian live-cd` with [`live-build`](https://salsa.debian.org/live-team/live-build) and [`debian-installer`](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/debian-installer).

I need a [`"Desktop" Debian Installer`](https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/html/live-manual/customizing-installer.en.html#643). As described in the manual:

> "Desktop" Debian Installer: Regardless of the type of Debian Installer included, d-i can be launched from the Desktop by clicking
> on an icon. This is user friendlier in some situations. In order to
> make use of this, the debian-installer-launcher package needs to be
> included.
>
> Note that by default, live-build does not include Debian
> Installer images in the images, it needs to be specifically enabled
> with lb config. Also, please note that for the "Desktop" installer to
> work, the kernel of the live system must match the kernel d-i uses for
> the specified architecture. For example:
>
> ```bash
> $ lb config --architectures i386 --linux-flavours 586 \
>     --debian-installer live 
> $ echo debian-installer-launcher >> config/package-lists/my.list.chroot
> ```

So, I used `lb config` to create a `live-cd` with `debian-installer` and `debian-installer-launcher` included and a kernel matching `d-i`'s kernel version.

I don't want to install the `live` system to disk, so I pass `--debian-installer cdrom` to install Debian by fetching and installing `.deb` packages using `debootstrap`, from local media.

```bash
lb config \
  --apt-recommends false \
  --apt-indices false \
  --architectures amd64 \
  --binary-images iso-hybrid \
  --debian-installer cdrom \
  --debian-installer-gui true \
  --distribution bullseye \
  --linux-packages "linux-image-5.10.0-20"

cat << EOF > config/package-lists/my.list.chroot
user-setup
sudo
debian-installer-launcher
task-lxde-desktop
EOF

lb build
```

The whole `build` process occurred well and finished with a `live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso` file.

I successfully booted this `ISO` and started the `live-cd`, but when I click on `Menu > System Tools > Install Debian` the Install process is stuck at the `Configure the package manager` step and I can't proceed.

The `Start Installer` option from the `GRUB` menu works nicely.

I found this old bug report on [`Debian mail list`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-live/2011/05/msg00165.html):

> Unfortunately, what you're probably running into is a battle between
> the live image and the installer about what to do with the network.
> The live image will configure the network one way (usually
> NetworkManager), then the installer will attempt to configure it its
> own way (using ifupdown, dropping connection in the live system).
> There are a couple of possible workarounds I can think of (but have
> not tested):
>
> 1. disconnect the network in the live system before doing an install and see what happens
> 2. run the installer with the network still up in the live system, but don't configure the network (d-i doesn't really give you an option to
>    do this; choose a network interface you know will fail because it's
>    not plugged in). since the live-installer installs from the contents
>    of the image, it doesn't actually need the network. unfortunately,
>    configuration of apt and the network then becomes a post-install step
>    the user has to deal with later.

But none of the workarounds work.

How can I create a `live-cd` that launches `debian-installer` and works properly?